# Softer fade-in transition for my JQuery slider isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to give my sliders a softer looking fade in animation using opacity properties along with trnsition and ease-in-out but for some reason it isn't working as intended, I want to make it really soft so instead of a white flash or something the slider images  slowly fades out and shows the next image . JQuery's fade-in and fade-out are too rough.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 
 var interval = 8000;
 var sliders = $('.slider');
 var dots = $('.dot');
 var index = 0;
 var show_index = 0;
 
 
 $('.slider').eq(show_index).addClass('active_slider');
 $('.dot').eq(show_index).addClass('active_dot');
 console.log(show_index);
 console.log(sliders.length);
 
 
 
 
 setInterval(function() {
        
  if(show_index == (sliders.length- 1)){
   
   
   $('.slider').eq(show_index).removeClass('active_slider');
            show_index = 0; // set it here
      $('.slider').eq(show_index).addClass('active_slider');
            $('.dot').removeClass('active_dot');   
   $('.dot').eq(show_index).addClass('active_dot');   
   console.log(show_index);
  }
  
  else{
   
   
   $('.slider').eq(show_index).removeClass('active_slider');
            show_index = show_index + 1; // set it here 
      $('.slider').eq(show_index).addClass('active_slider');
   $('.dot').removeClass('active_dot');   
   $('.dot').eq(show_index).addClass('active_dot');
            console.log(show_index);   
  }
  
    }, interval);
 
 
 
 
 $('.prev').click(function(){
  
  console.log('clicked prev');
  
  if(show_index == 0){
   
   
   $('.slider').eq(show_index).removeClass('active_slider');
            show_index = (sliders.length - 1);// set it here
      $('.slider').eq(show_index).addClass('active_slider');
            $('.dot').removeClass('active_dot');   
   $('.dot').eq(show_index).addClass('active_dot');   
   console.log(show_index);
  }
  
  else{
   
   $('.slider').eq(show_index).removeClass('active_slider');
            show_index = show_index - 1; // set it here 
      $('.slider').eq(show_index).addClass('active_slider');
   $('.dot').removeClass('active_dot');   
   $('.dot').eq(show_index).addClass('active_dot');
            console.log(show_index);   
  }
    });
 
 
 
 $('.next').click(function(){
  
  console.log('clicked next');
  
  if(show_index == (sliders.length- 1)){
   
   
   $('.slider').eq(show_index).removeClass('active_slider');
            show_index = 0; // set it here
      $('.slider').eq(show_index).addClass('active_slider');
            $('.dot').removeClass('active_dot');   
   $('.dot').eq(show_index).addClass('active_dot');
   console.log(show_index);
  }
  
  else{
   
   
   $('.slider').eq(show_index).removeClass('active_slider');
            show_index = show_index + 1; // set it here 
      $('.slider').eq(show_index).addClass('active_slider');
   $('.dot').removeClass('active_dot');   
   $('.dot').eq(show_index).addClass('active_dot');
            console.log(show_index);   
  }
    });
 
 
 
 
 $('.slider').each(function(){
        $('.gran_slider_big_navegation_container').append('<span class="dot"></span>');
    });
 
 
 
 $('.dot').click(function(){
        index = $(this).index();
  console.log(index);
        $('.slider').removeClass('active_slider'); 
     $('.slider').eq(index).addClass('active_slider');
  $('.dot').removeClass('active_dot');   
  $('.dot').eq(index).addClass('active_dot');
  show_index = index;
  
    });
 
 $(function() {
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        $('#background').css('margin-top', $(window).scrollTop() * -.3);
    });
});
 
 $(".responsive_nav_header_nav_menu_toggle").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
      $('.responsive_nav_header_nav_link').toggleClass('visible');
    });
 
 
 $(".rest_menu_options_texts_type").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var menu_type = $(this).attr("data-menu");
 console.log(menu_type);
   
 $('.rest_menu_item_container').removeClass('visible');
 $('.rest_menu_item_container[data-menu=' + menu_type + ']').addClass('visible');
    });
 
 
 
 
});
```

```css
.gran_slider_maincontainer{width:100%; height:100vh; display:flex; flex-direction:column; overflow:hidden;}
.gran_slider_big_container{width:100%; position:relative; height:90vh; overflow:hidden;}
.prev{cursor:pointer; position:absolute; left:20px; transition:all 1000ms ease; opacity:0; z-index:9999999999999999999999999999; top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%); font-size:20px; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);}
.next{cursor:pointer; position:absolute; right:20px; transition:all 1000ms ease; opacity:0; z-index:9999999999999999999999999999;  top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%); font-size:20px; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);}
.gran_slider_big_navegation_container{width:auto; height:30px; display:flex; align-items:center; position:absolute; bottom:25px; right:50px; z-index:9999999999999999999999999999;}
.dot{width:15px; height:15px;  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7); transition: all 2000ms ease; margin:0px 6px; border-radius:50%; cursor:pointer;}
.gran_slider_big_container:hover .prev{opacity:1;}
.gran_slider_big_container:hover .next{opacity:1;}
.gran_slider_big_item_container{display:none; opacity:0; transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out; width:100%; height:100%; position:relative; overflow:hidden;}
.gran_slider_big_item_gradient_overlay{width:100%; height:100%; z-index:3; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4); position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;}
.gran_slider_big_item_image{width:100%; height:100%; z-index:2; background-size:cover;}
.gran_slider_big_item_texts_container{width:55%; height:auto; display:flex; flex-direction:column; padding:10px;}
.gran_slider_big_item_texts_title{font-size:45px; color:white; font-weight:400; margin-bottom:30px; text-shadow:5px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1.0);}
.gran_slider_big_item_texts_description{font-size:30px; color:white; font-weight:400 margin-bottom:30px; text-shadow:5px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1.0);}
.gran_slider_small_container{width:100%; height:10vh; background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));}
.active_slider{display:flex; opacity:1;}
.active_dot{background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gran_slider_maincontainer" style="">
    <div class="gran_slider_big_container" style=" ">
     <i class="prev fa fa-chevron-left" style=""></i>
  <i class="next fa fa-chevron-right" style=""></i>
        <div class="gran_slider_big_navegation_container" style=" "></div>
     <div class="gran_slider_big_item_container slider" style="">
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_gradient_overlay" style=""></div>
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_image move" style="background-color:green;"></div>
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_container from_top_to_bottom_centered" style=" ">
       <span class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_title" style="">Titulo</span>
    <span class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_description" style="">Esta es una descripción que se mueve hacia la derecha, empezando por fuera de la derecha.</span>
   </div>
     </div>
  <div class="gran_slider_big_item_container slider" style="">
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_gradient_overlay" style=""></div>
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_image move" style="background-color:yellow;"></div>
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_container from_right_to_bottom" style=" ">
       <span class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_title" style="">Titulo</span>
    <span class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_description" style="">Esta es una descripción que se mueve hacia la derecha, empezando por fuera de la derecha.</span>
   </div>
     </div>
  <div class="gran_slider_big_item_container slider" style="">
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_gradient_overlay" style=""></div>
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_image move" style="background-color:red;"></div>
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_container from_right_to_bottom" style=" ">
       <span class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_title" style="">Titulo</span>
    <span class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_description" style="">Esta es una descripción que se mueve hacia la derecha, empezando por fuera de la derecha.</span>
   </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gran_slider_small_container" style=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you familiar with CSS transitions? You’ll get better performance and easier maintainability if you use CSS transitions. Create an ‘active’ class, or whatever you’d like to call it, and then add/remove that class as needed when your slides change. Then, in the CSS, for slower transitions you can just change the timing there.

Comment: `display:none;` in CSS, then `jQueryElement.fadeIn('slow')`.